# Null bitmap in Android Surfaceview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I'm attempting to get a bitmap from a camera preview in Android, then examine the bitmap and draw something to the screen based on what the camera is seeing. This all has to be done live due to the nature of the project I'm working on.

At the moment I'm using a surfaceview to display the live preview and I'm getting the bitmap using the following code I found on a separate question on here.

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    snipeCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

            ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
            YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
            yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());

            bit = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        }
    });
}
```

Bit is a:

```
public static Bitmap bit;
```

Whenever I try and access this bitmap anywhere else I get a null exception error. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it's being set inside setPreviewCallback, but I don't know enough about Android to fix it. Is there something I can do to get access to this bitmap? Or is there another way I can work with a live bitmap of what the camera is seeing?

Comment: "I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it's being set inside setPreviewCallback" -- more importantly, it has not been set yet. "Is there something I can do to get access to this bitmap?" -- put your code inside your existing `onPreviewFrame()` method, either directly or by having `onPreviewFrame()`, and get rid of the `static Bitmap`. Or, if the work to be done with the bitmap might take longer than you want on the main application thread, use an `AsyncTask` or something to do the work.

Comment: Beyond that, use a debugger or `Log` statements to confirm that your `decodeByteArray()` method is being invoked and is returning a non-`null` `Bitmap`, and get rid of the `copy()` call to save heap space and CPU time.

Comment: If I put my code inside the existing    OnPreviewFrame() method, I can't draw to the screen, can I?

Comment: "If I put my code inside the existing OnPreviewFrame() method, I can't draw to the screen, can I?" -- either `onPreviewFrame()` is called on the main application thread, or it is not. If it is called on the main application thread, you are welcome to update your UI. If not, you can use an event bus, or `post()`, or `runOnUiThread()`, or a `Handler`, to arrange to run some code on the main application thread.

Comment: Sorry, my response was unclear. Right now the surfaceview is locked for drawing because the camera is locking it constantly. My initial thought was so get this bitmap, modify the pixels I need, and then draw it using a separate surface. I haven't been able to pass this data to a separate view. Can I draw to the surface inside this function?

Comment: "Right now the surfaceview is locked for drawing because the camera is locking it constantly" -- AFAIK, you cannot draw on that `SurfaceView` anyway, so that should be a moot point. You draw on something else that is overlaying the `SurfaceView` or is containing the `SurfaceView`. "I haven't been able to pass this data to a separate view" -- I do not know what you mean by that. If you are on the main application thread, you are certainly welcome to call, say, `setImageBitmap()` on an `ImageView`.

Comment: I think the concept that I'm struggling to get past is that this bmp is a local variable to this function. How is the ImageView, or some other view supposed to get the bitmap?

Comment: "How is the ImageView, or some other view supposed to get the bitmap?" -- call `yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)`, where `yourImageView` is your `ImageView`. Your code snippet from your question seems to be from a `SurfaceHolder`; that `SurfaceHolder` would need to have a reference to your `ImageView` (e.g., `ImageView yourImageView` as a field) that you populate as appropriate.

Comment: Oh I see! This is actually making a lot of sense now. Is there any way you could add this as a response so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something I can do to get access to this bitmap?

You already have access to your `Bitmap`. You are getting it from `decodeByteArray()`.

(note that I am assuming that the code leading up to and including `decodeByteArray()` is correct — there could be additional problems lurking in there)

You just need to consume the `Bitmap` in your `onPreviewFrame()` method. If your work to do is quick (sub-millisecond), probably just do that work right there. If your work to do is not-so-quick, you'll now need to work out background threading plans, arranging to update your UI with the results of that work on the main application thread, and related issues.

If, to consume the `Bitmap`, you need access to other objects in your camera UI, just makes sure that the `SurfaceHolder` has references to those other objects. Your `onPreviewFrame()` method is in an anonymous inner class inside the `SurfaceHolder`, and `onPreviewFrame()` has access to everything that the `SurfaceHolder` has.

Comment: Apparently I am having some funky issues with the bitmap code, it's returning null. Otherwise, this is working for me. Thanks so much for the help!